# Synthetic geometry: if a line L does not pass through the centre $q$ of $K$, then inversion in $K$ maps $L$ to a circle that passes through $q$

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

The claim is that: if a line L does not pass through the centre $q$ of $K$, then inversion in $K$ maps $L$ to a circle that passes through $q$; where $b$ is an arbitrary point on $L$ while $a$ is the intersection of $L$ with the perpendicular line through $q$. But how can I prove this synthetic-geometrically, i.e. without algebra?

Now, I've been thinking about this for a while. By Thales' theorem, drawing a circle with diameter $\tilde{a}q$ will necessarily allow for the constitution of a right trangle $q\tilde{b}\tilde{a}$, and the author mentions that the triangle $q\tilde{b}\tilde{a}$ is similar to the triangle $qab$, and this also follows from Thales' theorem. Furthermore, since $\tilde{b}\tilde{a}$ is a line that intersects perpendicularly a line through $q$, $\tilde{b}$ is necessarily the circle inversion of some point, which happens to be $b$ if we draw the two tangent lines of $b$ with $K$, but this seems to happen completely coincidentally.

The proof is easier with algebra, but how come $\tilde{b}$ necessarily produces the inversion of $b$ in $K$? Any ideas of synthetic geometrical theorems which could help?

If this helps anyone, here are the geometrical constructions following the fact that both $\tilde{b},\tilde{a}$ are inversions:

[image]

Figure [3], by the way, is from Needham's Visual Complex Analysis, page 127.

EDIT: thanks to user Oussema for pointing out the solution to similarity between $qba$ and $q\tilde{b}\tilde{a}$!

Comment: Do you know cyclic quadrilaterals?

Comment: @Oussema all I know is the one from Euclid, https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookIII/propIII22.html

Comment: I have a synthetic geometric proof but it's a little bit long since I'll have to prove some results about cyclic quadrilaterals and power of a point along the way.

Comment: Would be very interested in seeing it, just assume those parts which depend on some known theorems! This is a problem I've been coming back to for two weeks, and will come back to in the future, so if I find a faster solution along the way I'll ping you!

Comment: However, I want to make sure I understand what you're looking for. You are trying to prove that the image of a line not passing through the origin by an inversion is a circle which goes through the origin, right?

Comment: @Oussema right, I get stuck specifically at the fact that given $b$, it follows that $\tilde{b}$ is related by inversion, but if you find a proof that bypasses the need for this question, it would do the job!

Comment: @Oussema I think I found one: create midpoint on $qb$. Then the parallels of $b$ with $K$ are necessarily right angled, which guarantees that $\tilde{b}$ is an inversion of $b$!

Comment: I don't follow your argument. You should probably create a self answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123208/discussion-between-shintuku-and-oussema).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proposition 1:** $ABCD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral if and only if $\angle ABD = \angle ACD$.

One direction $(\implies)$ can be proved using the inscribed angle theorem.

We can prove the other direction by contradiction. We suppose that there is a quadrilateral $ABCD$ such that $\angle ABC = \angle ABD = 180^\circ$ but $B$ is not on $\Gamma$ the circumcircle of $\triangle ABD$. We then take $B'$ to be the intersection of the segment $BD$ with $\Gamma$. Using Proposition 1, we find that $B = B'$ from which our contradiction follows.

With that in mind, let's prove our second proposition:

**Proposition 2:** If $\tilde{a}$ and $\tilde{b}$ are the inverses around $q$ of $a$ and $b$ respectively, then $\angle qab = \angle q\tilde b\tilde{a}$.
[image: prop 2]

By definition, $qa \cdot q\tilde{a} = qb \cdot q\tilde b$.
This is equivalent to, $\dfrac {qa} {qb} = \dfrac{q\tilde b}{q \tilde a}$ which means that $\triangle qab \sim \triangle q \tilde{b} \tilde{a}$

Therefore, $\angle qa b = \angle q\tilde b\tilde{a}$.

Now we have 3 collinear points $a,b$ and $c$. And we want to prove that the inversion around $q$ transforms them into a circle going through $q$.
[image: question]
In order to do that, we just need to prove that $q\tilde a \tilde b \tilde c$ is cyclic.

We have by the collinearity of $a,b,c$, $\angle qab = \angle qac$ (if you don't want to worry about configuration issues you can use directed angles)

Using proposition 2, this means that $\angle q \tilde b \tilde a  = \angle q \tilde c \tilde a $.

Finally, by proposition 1, $q\tilde a \tilde b \tilde c$ is a circle which finishes the proof.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to user Oussema for an important idea here. Create the following construction:
[image]

Where $C$ is a circle with center $c$, and $c$ is a midpoint on $bD$. Then, by Thales' theorem, any intersections $I1, I2$ of the circle C with circle $K$ will generate tangents of $K$ with $b$ (since the angles are, by Thales theorem, right angled), and therefore, the intersection of $I1I2$ with $bD$ will by definition be the inversion of $b$ in $K$, $b^*$!